# Oauth tokens storing in MySQL database does not work but works fine when using sessions

Tags: php, mysql, oauth

I'm trying to create app with 4shared API but to use it I need to authorize in 4shared using Oauth. The problem is that when I'm using sessions to store oauth_token everything works fine, but when I'm trying to store tokens in MySQL database I'm getting error:

```
OAuthException:  No server with consumer_key "MY_CONSUMER_KEY" has been registered (for this user)object(OAuthException2)#3 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(98) "No server with consumer_key "MY_CONSUMER_KEY" has been registered (for this user)"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(68) "/usr/share/nginx/4shared/library/store/OAuthStoreSQL.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(453)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(63) "/usr/share/nginx/4shared/library/OAuthRequester.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(155)
      ["function"]=>
      string(9) "getServer"
      ["class"]=>
      string(13) "OAuthStoreSQL"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(32) "MY_CONSUMER_KEY"
        [1]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(46) "/usr/share/nginx/4shared/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(52)
      ["function"]=>
      string(19) "requestRequestToken"
      ["class"]=>
      string(14) "OAuthRequester"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
      ["args"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(32) "MY_CONSUMER_KEY"
        [1]=>
        int(0)
        [2]=>
        array(3) {
          ["scope"]=>
          string(28) "https://api.4shared.com/v1_2"
          ["xoauth_displayname"]=>
          string(13) "Oauth 4Shared"
          ["oauth_callback"]=>
          string(41) "https://example.com/4shared/index.php"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

I have created proper MySQL database and imported mysql.sql file into it from Oauth's store folder. Also If I'm not using 'conn' as an Option it does not connect to database at all, but I'm able to connect to DB with 'conn' option.

Here is my code:

```
include_once "library/OAuthStore.php";
include_once "library/OAuthRequester.php";

define("FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY", "MY_CONSUMER_KEY");
define("FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_SECRET", "MY_SECRET_KEY");
define("FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST", "https://api.4shared.com");
define("FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST_SEARCH", "https://search.4shared.com");
define("FOURSHARED_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/initiate");
define("FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/authorize");
define("FOURSHARED_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/token");
define('OAUTH_TMP_DIR', function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ? sys_get_temp_dir() : realpath($_ENV["TMP"]));


define("FOURSHARED_OAUTH_CALLBACK", "https://example.com/4shared/index.php");    

//  Inicia o OAuthStore
$options = array(
    'consumer_key' => FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, 
    'consumer_secret' => FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    'server_uri' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST,
    'request_token_uri' => FOURSHARED_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
    'authorize_uri' => FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL,
    'access_token_uri' => FOURSHARED_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    //'server' => 'localhost',
    //'username' => 'oauth',
    //'password' => 'password',
    //'database' => 'oauth',
    'conn' => new mysqli('localhost','oauth','password','oauth')
);

// Store token in database or sessions
// Choose a database.
OAuthStore::instance("MySQLi", $options);

try
{
    //  Step 1: If there is not an OAuth token yet, we need one.
    if (empty($_GET["oauth_token"]))
    {
        $getAuthTokenParams = array(
            'scope' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . '/v1_2',
            'xoauth_displayname' => 'Oauth 4Shared',
            'oauth_callback' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_CALLBACK
        );

        // Request a request token
        $tokenResultParams = OAuthRequester::requestRequestToken(FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, 0, $getAuthTokenParams);

        // Redirects to the authorization page. Here the user will give you permissions the first time and then be redirected back to your site.
        header("Location: " . FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL . "?oauth_token=" . $tokenResultParams['token']);
    }
    else {
        //  Step 2: Request an access token
        $oauthToken = $_GET["oauth_token"];
        $tokenResultParams = $_GET;

        try {
            OAuthRequester::requestAccessToken(FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, $oauthToken, 0, 'POST', $_GET);
        }
        catch (OAuthException2 $e)
        {
            var_dump($e);
            return;
        }
        // We will request user information
        $request = new OAuthRequester(FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST_SEARCH . '/v1_2/files', 'GET', $tokenResultParams);
        $result = $request->doRequest(0);
        if ($result['code'] == 200) {
            // Convert string to json object
            $files_result = json_decode($result['body']);

            // Print the screen on the e-mail;
            print_r($files_result);
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
}
catch(OAuthException2 $e) {
    echo "OAuthException:  " . $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
    
}
```

Everything works fine when I'm changing  `OAuthStore::instance("MySQLi", $options);` to  `OAuthStore::instance("sessions", $options);`

As requested by commenter:
MySQL version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

my.cnf content (though I have many other databases on same server and those are working fine so shouldn't be problem with that):

```
[mysqld]

# Basic configuration
port=3306
server_id=0

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysqltmp
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# Logging
log_error=/var/log/mysqld-error.log
slow_query_log=ON
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysqld-slow.log
general_log=OFF
general_log_file=/var/log/mysqld-general.log

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%. Default is 128M.
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Set the number of open tables. This has a huge effect on memory usage. Default value is 2000.
#table_open_cache=2000

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
#log_bin

# Optionally change the SQL mode.
#sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers. The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs. Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
#join_buffer_size = 128M
#sort_buffer_size = 2M
#read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

I'm also linking to a file with which I created the database (this is file provided by oauth):
https://pastebin.com/2eb0aTbL

Comment: Can you put your MySQL Table Schema as well?

Comment: please also state your current MySQL version and also the content of the my.cnf ?

Comment: When using "OAuthStore::instance("MySQLi", $options);", you are uncommenting the server/auth part in the options, right (seems obvious, but not shown in the question - could be a simple miss like that....) - also, as asked - what does the table in the database look like?  It appears that you just don't have the right permissions to create/update data in the OAuthStore function - - - no data stored, nothing works!  Verify that there is a table and it is populated (also, the table name is not shown in the options so it is likely hardcoded in the class).

Comment: There is two ways to connect (as it's shown in Manual) either with username, password ect in options or with 'conn' as single option. When using username password ect it does not connect to database at all.. while using 'conn' it connects but throws listed error.
And There should be no problem with permissions as I'm testing it with Root user and password. I think I need somehow register server? As it states in OAuthException: No server with consumer_key "MY_CONSUMER_KEY" has been registered. But I cant find anything about that in manual.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think you are creating instance not properly.

can you check below link for a various example of Oauth Instance Creation?

[php-oauthstore-instance-method-examples](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/OAuthStore/instance/php-oauthstore-instance-method-examples.html)

```
function get_db_options()
{
    return array('server' => DB_HOST, 'username' => DB_USERNAME, 'password' => DB_PASSWORD, 'database' => DB_NAME);
}

$oauth = OAuthStore::instance('MySQL', get_db_options());
```

For Mysqli use below code to connect

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

OAuthStore::instance('MySQLi', array('conn' => $con, 'table_prefix' => UserConfig::$mysql_prefix));
```

Comment: You just showing me different way to connect to database. It does connect to database with example I wrote in the question, because otherwise it would throw Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException2: Could not connect to MySQL database. And with your given example for Mysqli it throws error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'UserConfig' not found also. And anyway the problem is NOT with connecting to DB, because script connects to database as I said. I need to register server with consumer key somehow I guess.

Comment: @DadaB pass $conn object instead of UserConfig::getDb()

Comment: Ya, but there is another userConfig class defined next to $mysql_prefix table prefix variable. I don't see anything related to table prefix in code so I can change to that. Thanks for trying to help me btw.

Comment: Ok so I added table prefix manually  (OAuthStore::instance('MySQLi', array('conn' => $con, 'table_prefix' => 'oct'));) because this is prefix used in tables and getting same error as in question. As I said in comment before, It does connect to database, so problem is somewhere else